# VS Code JS: Why / when do definitions break?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code for JavaScript.
Definitions within a file work sometimes, but not others. Does anyone know why they fail?
In this example, VS Code finds the definition for `edit` easily. There is no occurrence of the word 'something' anywhere else in this file. Completely unique. So, why can't VS Code find its definition?

[image]

If I knew why, maybe I could change my code to work around it.

VS Code also can't find any references to these 'lost' properties. Which is very frustrating for tracking down where a function is called etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a length limit. IntelliSense will define type `:any` if an object description is too long.

There is no way around this at all. The `:any` type will overwrite imported type definitions (e.g., a `.d.ts` file).
Two solutions:

1. Don't write long object declarations in your code.
2. Don't use VS Code or IntelliSense.

As for specifics:

The behavior is unpredictable.

1. If a type definition does not generate, reducing the object description length will not cause it to generate
2. Reducing an object description length to below the limit and re-launching VS Code will cause it to re-generate.

The length limit is unpredictable.

1. A function definition is 'longer' than a string, even if they have the same character count.
2. A nested ('deep') object declaration is longer than a shallow ('flat') object declaration, even if they have the same character count.

In short: IntelliSense breaks irreparably if you try to write long object declarations in a JS file.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this length limit?

Comment: Personal research only. If you know of any mention in any documentation anywhere, I would love to add it here. (Am I just the first coder ever to try writing a long object description in VS Code?)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `this`.

```js
const edit = {
  something: 5,
  test() {
    this.something;
  },
};
```

You must not use an arrow function for `test` field, or `this` would point elsewhere but not the `edit` object.

EDIT: In TypeScript 4.3.5, the latest version of TS at the time of writing, TS is able to detect self-references in object literals, and both `edit.something` and `this.something` would work. For the case of working with JavaScript, upgrading VS Code should do the trick.

[A TS playground link for reference.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgEwJawLwwN4CgYwiAWzigAskwBzALhgFYAaHGKOaACgEpMndSkIAdPiJ9KAbh7xkUIYWJlxTAL6MlEoA)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but to clarify, my code runs perfectly.
The only problem is VS Code can't resolve the definitions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers
This question might relate to your concerns. :P

Comment: OP is not using `this`. They refer to the constant `edit`, which should have a type definition available.

Comment: Thank you, @Bergi .   
@T.D.Stoneheart , my question is really about VS Code. `edit` should have a type definition. For some reason, its definition is `any`.

Comment: I guess TS hasn't been able to detect self references in the object literal declaration yet.

Comment: @MichaelG @Bergi Maybe upgrading TypeScript or VS Code would work, as TS could determine the type when referring to both `this` and `edit`, at least at TS 3.3.3 in the TS Playground.

Comment: @T.D.Stoneheart , this is a randomly occurring bug, _not_ a problem with my code or environment. I am looking for clues as to why and when type definitions can fail.

For example, if I open this same file on a new machine, the type definition may or may not populate. The behavior can differ over SSH versus over a local connection, and changes to the file may make the bug re-emerge or vanish again.

There is no simple answer to my question. I am looking for others who have experienced the same.

Comment: "this is a randomly occurring bug", I've witnessed this in my TS env sometimes, and fix it by re-starting the TS Server. I think the most likely cause is a parsing error when you're mid-editing a file which does not clean up during a later re-parse once you've finished editing; VS Code is running the server against the working version and not the saved version of the file so you get hints as you type.